# Correct type for Canvas element

Tags: flowtype

I am trying to figure out the correct types for canvas element.
Whatever I do - it does not work. I have tried all possible html element types but flow says they are incompatible. So why cant I assign canvas element to HTMLCanvasElement variable?

Any ideas?

The node parameter is a div element which contains canvas element. It is simple really. If I strip the types, everything works.

```
export class Graph extends Component {
      draw = (node: HTMLDivElement) => {
        let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = node.firstChild
        if (canvas){
          canvas.width = parseInt(getComputedStyle(node).getPropertyValue('width'))
          canvas.height = parseInt(getComputedStyle(node).getPropertyValue('height'))
        }
        let chart = new Chart(canvas, {
          type: this.props.type,
          data: this.props.data
        })
      }
      render = () => (
        <div ref={this.draw} className='graph'>
          <canvas />
        </div>
      )
    }
```

I get these errors from flow linter:

```
Node This type is incompatible with HTMLCanvasElement
null This type is incompatible with HTMLCanvasElement
undefined This type is incompatible with HTMLCanvasElement
```

Thanks

P.S. It is Inferno  - not React. So the ref is a function, not a string. Just to avoid people correcting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `HTMLDivElement` is not defined in Flow internals:
https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.43.1/lib/dom.js#L2811

`HTMLDivElement` and `HTMLCanvasElement` are sibling types (both children of `HTMLElement`), so naturally Flow will say it's unsafe to try to cast `HTMLDivElement` to `HTMLCanvasElement` since you generally never want to do this in any typed system.

You can beat Flow's type system and get around this by casting `node.firstChild` to `any`. This is usually not recommended, but seems acceptable in this case since `HTMLDivElement` doesn't give you anything and you definitely know what it is.

```
let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = (node.firstChild: any)
```

[feel free to also view the flowtype.org/try link](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljjQBsUBnFuAcShTAAs4aMJADsAJu2ToYAOgDCuSMJHwA3uThxR3AO5wAvHAAUwiKKQAuOAAkAKgFkAMgBFgANwCijJCGUBKfQB8cGoaGl7waCjCrqyWto6yUTEsnt7K+kYmZtKYwFAsMLK8wIyillEAnr7qocCYRpHRrL4hoRqNydLawKIw-AZgKPlIAJLCMIYA5kiFCgCuQqIAyjAVXsamSL7S0zAACjhgSLAVAGoojHNIhvjdvbz4vtVt7Ums0rxIwJO88ANDLFG4ymM3k4AWSGWq3WWS2OxmBwgRxO50u13wn2+v0ez1CAF8amEZgxeEM-nAlLoimTDB1WAAaYKE0KrI6WPrAFjSMCHLmspD05kaUQoGAodnFLk8pFckVi5l43EaAkaIhiY4ZQz+PRBQzMgA8ojccCImD0Kg5sp0eIYzDYADkUD49PhJtw+PgAkK4Pq6ewAPRetr6-1G1xBuDVPFAA)

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion. But I avoid using `any`. It kind of defeats the point of a type system. I know I could work around like this. So what type of  variable can I assign canvas element?

Comment: in terms of how much exposure using `any` in this case will have to the rest of the types, it shouldn't have much because you're only casting `node.firstChild` to `any` in order to recast it to `HTMLCanvasElement` to get around the typecasting restrictions in Flow.

Comment: While it might be possible to define a better HTMLDivElement type, it's going to be very difficult to define something generic that understands the type of `node.firstChild`. You might be able to define a non-generic child type of HTMLDivElement that defines node.firstChild to be your HTMLCanvasElement

Comment: OK. If there is no other way around it, I'll just have to go with any for now. Not the end of the world. I'll give you the tick. Thanks for your help.